# release object in abp unit of work method

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

i resolve an object in unitofwork method,and the object dependency a IRepository.
I release the object then use another IRepository in the unitofwork method,it will throw dbcontext disposed error.Must I release the object from DI?

```
private readonly IIocManager _iocManager;
    private readonly IRepository<Bill> _billRepository;

    public PayService(IIocManager iocManager,IRepository<Bill> billRepository)
    {
        this._iocManager = iocManager;
        _billRepository = billRepository;
    }


    [AbpAuthorize]
    public PayRestultDto SwingCard(PayDto input)
    {
        var itr = _iocManager.IocContainer.Resolve<ITradeOrder>(input.PayType.ToString("G"));
        PayRestultDto result;
        try
        {
            result = itr.Pay(input);
        }
        finally
        {
            _iocManager.IocContainer.Release(itr);
        }
        if (result != null)
        {
            _billRepository.Insert(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code for `ITradeOrder`, and the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the constructor arguments in an instance of an anonymous type. See how it's done for your case;

```cs
var itr = _iocManager.IocContainer.Resolve<ITradeOrder>(new { PayType = input.PayType.ToString("G") });
```

where **PayType** is the parameter name in constructor of TradeOrder class.

---

- For others to know how to resolve an interface with constructor arguments

```cs
IFoo foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(new { Param1 = "Value1", Param2 = "Value2"});
```

---

- If you are using an old version of C# which does not support anonymous types, you can use dictionary

```cs
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("Param1", "Value1");
parameters.Add("Param2", "Value2");
IFoo foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(parameters );
```